# In angular select dropdown get both name and id as values

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
<select (change)="select($event.target.value)" [ngModel]="gen"
        class="border border-gray-200 bg-white h-10 pl-6 pr-40 rounded-lg text-sm focus:outline-none appearance-none block cursor-pointer"
        id="gender" required>
        <option value="" disabled="true" selected hidden>Select Gen</option>
        <option [value]="{ id: g.id, name: g.name }" *ngFor="let g of genObj">{{g.name}}</option>
      </select>

selectGenre({id,name}): void {
    console.log(id,name,'genre')
  }

genObj - 
    0: {id: 2, name: "xcv"}
    1: {id: 3, name: "ert"}
```

How can I get both ID and name by selecting dropdown values?
Tried passing 'g.id' and 'g.name' but I get undefined in both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nufxro?file=src/app/app.component.html  i made this one , you can try it.

Comment: Getting null in the console if I select any value.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to save, try now